# How to get length of json object array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, variable-length

I wrote a restService and my service returns me two different result :

```
{"Response": {
"cars":[
{"id":"1",
"name":"test1"},
{"id":"2",
"name":"test2"},
{"id":"3",
"name":"test3"}
],
"books":[
{"id":"4",
"name":"example1"},
{"id":"5",
"name":"example2"},
{"id":"6",
"name":"example3"}    
]}}
```

and second ,

```
{"Response": {
"cars":{
"id":"1",
"name":"test1"},
"books":{
"id":"4",
"name":"example1"}
}}
```

I will show the result in my dataTable with javascript. For this, I want to learn length of cars or books. If result `>1` I can get length, cars or books act as an array,but if result `<1` it acts as an object and I can't get length of objects .In my restService, I defined as an `ArrayList` the cars and books. Is there any solutions for this ? Thanks for responses.

Comment: `var len = Array.isArray(Response.cars) ? Response.cars.length : 1`

Comment: @adeneo I tried this but when I write `Response.cars[i]` in a for loop, it can't show to me because of it is a object

Comment: Look closely, `Array.isArray(Response.cars)` <- that's how you know it's an array, if that fails, it's not an array, so you don't do a `for` loop at all.

Comment: Thanks @adeneo, yes you are right , it is a solution to learn it's an array or not,I'm sure it is an array, and I want to do a for loop at all.

Answer (score 3):

The problem lies with your REST Service, make it always return a list of cars, even if there is only one car.

Comment: I've also seen lots of examples of returning a "count" variable with your JSON, just to make it easier to work with.

Comment: Yes, that is unfortunately pretty common. My personal opinion is that metadata like that does not belong in a JSON response. Either use an array for that data, or pass the metadata in a separate structure. (Or use XML and pass the count as an attribute, if you want to be able to read it without parsing the full structure)

Comment: @folkol but my REST Service returns list of Response, not list of cars ?

Comment: Yes, but I was talking about the value called "cars", make sure that it is always a list, even when there is only one car (Or no cars for that matter).

Comment: `List<Car> cars= new ArrayList<Car>();
cars= result.getSelectedCars();   Response.setCars(cars);` 
I think you want to say like this , but it did not work

Comment: What API do you use for serialization? I think that old Jackson libraries tried to be smart about empty or single element lists.

Comment: I didn't notice , I'll search this, thanks for response @folkol